# Using awk to print a column if it matches regex

Tags: regex, bash, awk

I'm trying to get awk to print the sixth column *IF* it matches my regex but right now it returns just 1.

```bash
awk -v OFS='\t' {'print $3, $4, $5, $6 ~ /([^07].*)/'}
```

What am I missing here? I can't really use grep because the fourth column begins with the same characters as the sixth column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want it to print the column if it starts with 07

Your syntax is wrong, you need to use:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '$6 ~ /^07/ {print $3, $4, $5, $6}' file
```

i.e. match regex as a condition and then print selected columns in `{...}` block.

Comment: Thanks but it seems like it ignores the regex and just prints the column anyway.

`5861511 0740910000      31832134        0734378922`

`5861511 0740910000      31832134        30`

`5861511 0740910000      31832134        39`

Comment: Ah, thanks. :)

I want it to print the column if it starts with **07**.